# Suitability of app for AWS Step Functions

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have a use case that I need to implement using aws lambda functions. I have two or more functions that make calls to web service to get data with a criteria. I need to use results from all the process, compare it against other input criteria and produce a final result.

My question is:
Is it a good idea to implement the web service function as a lambda step up function executing in parallel? 
If so, do I need a another lambda function to process results. And will the final lambda wait for the completion of execution of parallel lambda functions to complete.
And how will the final lambda get the outputs from all the parallel lambda functions as input?

Answer (score 0):

This is the ideal usecase for Step Functions.

If you want to orchestrate multiple lambda and have dependencies among each other, Step Functions is one of the way to accomplish to complete the task in a scalable way.

While there are other technologies such as streams, SQS available to decouple services. All orchestrations need to be done manually.

With Step Functions, you can take output of one lambda and feed as input of another lambda.

**Step Functions:**

https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/details/

Hope it helps.